# Replace the date value on one cell in R

Tags: r, date, select, replace

I would replace the date value in a single cell, but I didn't find the way to do...

```r
## dataframe = these_ac
## Anonymat = one of the variables
## these_ac$Anonymat == 17725 : the ligne I want to select
## entree = a date variable

these_ac[these_ac$Anonymat == 17725, "entree"] <- 1993-03-22
```

Comment: (1) `1993-03-22` is not a date, it's an arithmetic expression that resolves to 1968, you likely want it quoted, possibly more: `"1993-03-22"` or `as.Date("1993-03-22")`. (2) If you want to replace it where `Anonymat == 17725`, then why is your conditional `Anonymat == 1`?

Comment: t would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you Ronak, I will do this for the next time

Comment: r2evans, I have corrected this mistake, the solution is : these_ac[these_ac$Anonymat == 17725, "entree"] <- as.Date("1993-03-22") ?

Answer (score 0):

`these_ac["entree"][these_ac["Anonymat"] == 17725] <- "22/03/1993"`

I think it's one way to do this.

It works in my case.